# Книга MacDonald (и WPF и XAML) или Petzold (WPF на примерах кода и потом XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, книги

Присмотрел две книги с двумя разными подходами.
У Мэтью Мак-Дональда в книге ["Pro WPF 4.5 in C#: Windows Presentation Foundation"](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-4-5-Presentation-Foundation/dp/1430243651/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1413293047&sr=1-4&keywords=Windows+Presentation+Foundation) 2012 года идет изучение технологии совместно с демонстрацией языка XAML.
У Чарльза Петцольда в книге [Applications = Code + Markup: A Guide to the Microsoft](http://www.amazon.com/Applications-Code-Markup-Microsoft%C2%AE-Presentation/dp/0735619573/ref=la_B000APETXO_1_8?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1413293258&sr=1-8) 2006 года идет голое изучение на коде C#, и где-то к концу он уже немного затрагивает XAML. Но, насколько я знаю, Петцольд очень подробно и хорошо описывает материал.

Собственно, из-за этого возник вопрос, какую из двух книг лучше выбрать или прочитать обе, но в каком порядке тогда? Или, может, есть варианты получше?

Comment: IMHO начните с чистого C#, потом подключите WPF.

Comment: @VladD, мне если только уходить в дебри CLR via C# дальше, но я планировал это отложить на потом. А так сейчас использую ASP.NET MVC 3 и WinForms, который хочу заменить на WPF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну что же, я составил личное мнение по своему же вопросу.

***Чарльз Петцольд - Applications = Code
+ Markup: A Guide to the Microsoft***

Книга в основном на примерах кода C# показывает, как устроен WPF и довольно детально и глубоко обрисовывает его работу. Приведенные программы имитируют реальные приложения и ситуации, которые могут встретиться. Однако все это идет в ущерб простоте объяснения.

Книга очень тяжела для чтения, информация накапливается, как снежный ком. К середине для иллюстрирования 15-20 строчек текста приводятся трех- четырех-, а то и восьмистраничные листинги кода, причем в них очень много кода уходит только на основу для самого примера. Кажется, что середина сплошь состоит их листингов и от текста остается только четвертая часть. В общем, я бы не рекомендовал ее как первую книгу для чтения, но определенно она заслуживает внимания для ознакомления.

***Мэтью Мак-Дональда - Pro WPF 4.5 in C#: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4.5***

Хорошая и детальная книга по WPF. Начинается с разбора XAML, который в дальнейшем только упрощает как понимание работы, так и сокращает те чудовищные (но необходимые без XAML) листинги Петцольда. Примеры также просты и лаконичны, созданы исключительно для демонстрации необходимого. Каждой детали уделяется пристальное внимание, а для неизученных моментов в книге есть полно отсылок на другие главы с кратким пояснением, что значительно разгружает мозг. В общем, из двух приведенных я бы рекомендовал именно ее.

***Так же, для ознакомления оставлю похожий вопрос с stackoverflow:***

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591/what-wpf-books-would-you-recommend

P.S. Чуть позже закрою, спасибо всем ответившим.

Answer (score 3):

Берите обе, в любом случае не прогадаете. Тут логика простая, прочитать две книжки в любом случае лучше чем одну - пользы больше!

**Обновление**

Времени на это не мало надо. Например, книга Мак-Дональда имеет около 1000 страниц, которые нужно осилить. Поэтому для быстрого старта я бы посоветовал пройти какой-нибудь курс в центрах обучения, вроде Специалиста, а потом или параллельно с этим читать книжку, т.к. один курс вряд ли раскроет  вам всю суть и глубину технологии.

Comment: Ну, тут, скорее, вопрос времени, а также частоты и простоты использования XAML в приложениях.

Comment: @Alex Krass, обновил ответ.